# Buildbot having issues with GitPoller

Tags: git, buildbot

I've setup Buildbot and I'm trying to run a Gitpoller to check for changes to code. I'm getting the following error inside the twistd.log on the master machine.

```
2012-08-22 17:10:50+1000 [-] http client disconnected before results were sent
2012-08-22 17:11:11+1000 [-] http client disconnected before results were sent
2012-08-22 17:11:21+1000 [-] gitpoller: polling git repo at <git repo censored>
2012-08-22 17:11:31+1000 [-] gitpoller: repo poll failed
2012-08-22 17:11:31+1000 [-] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: twisted.internet.utils._UnexpectedErrorOutput: got stderr: "fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.\nUse '--' to separate paths from revisions\n"

2012-08-22 17:11:31+1000 [-] gitpoller: no changes, no catch_up
```

I have SSH keys setup on the master and on the slave and both copied into Github. Anyone have any ideas what this could be?

I'm running the latest version of Buildbot .8.6

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Hello there, If you're trying to poll a git repo with Buildbot 0.8.X by using SSH, they're having some issues with that. You should follow this thread on their TRAC[1].

Apparently they're currently working on it.

[1] http://trac.buildbot.net/ticket/2343

Answer (score 2):

A workarround that worked for me was to remove the gitpoller work dir (gitpoller-workdir) and then restart buildbot, as sugested in a message from the link in the accepted answer.